# How to create a log collection service using nodejs？

Tags: node.js, logging

I need to build a log collection system.

I find out that common log collection schemes include elk and Hadoop / hive.

1、As a front-end developer, can I spend a certain amount of time (for example, one week) to complete simple construction without a service-side foundation?

2、Can I use nodejs, mongodb and other technology stacks to build a log system？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ELK already includes LogStash or Filebeat exactly for this purpose; you don't need Node to collect log files.

For Hadoop (and Elasticsearch), it uses Log4j, which offer different appenders to write to external locations and/or log files on disk. With files on disk, you'd use Filebeat (or FluentD) to process those files and send to external locations, such as Apache Kafka topics, which can be read into Hadoop and/or Elasticsearch (or Splunk) for analytics. Mongo generally isn't well suited for log analysis or plaintext log searching.

For handling logs from Node services, they can also write to disk using standard NPM libraries, then tools listed above would treat those the same as logs from other services.